# Why does using .html() break this Replace expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

While working on a project I ran across a bug and found this unexpected behaviour:

If I call `.replace()` on a string and set the result to a div using `.text()` the replace function works as I expect.

However, if I call `.replace()` on a string and set the result to a div using `.html()`, the targeted text is not replaced in the string.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```js
 $('#result1').text('¤cyId'.replace('¤cyId','&currencyId')); // works
 $('#result2').html('¤cyId'.replace('¤cyId','&currencyId')); // doesnt work 

    var result = '¤cyId'.replace('¤cyId','&currencyId')
 $('#result3').text(result); // works
 $('#result4').html(result); // doesnt work
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1"></div><br>
<div id="result2"></div><br>
<div id="result3"></div><br>
<div id="result4"></div>
```

I see that using `.text()` instead of `.html()` resolves the issue, but...

**Why does this happen?**

Comment: *"the targeted text is not replaced in the string"* - No, the targeted text *is* replaced. It's what happens when the result is treated as html that is causing your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The replaces works just fine.

It only looks like the wrong string ends up in the elements when you use the `html` method because `&curren` is decoded into `¤` by the browser, so `&currencyId` is shown as `¤cyId`.

When you use the `text` method the text is not decoded as HTML code, so `.text("&currencyId")` has the same effect as`.html("&amp;currencyId")`.

The HTML entity for the `¤` character is `&curren;`, but the browser also accepts the form `&curren` without the semicolon.

Comment: Ah, it never occurred to me that "the browser also accepts the form &curren without the semicolon". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because &curren is a html entity, and .html resolves html entities whilst .text leaves them verbatim.

Comment: So to be clear, the `.replace()` statement works every time.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#result2').html('¤cyId'.replace('¤cyId','&amp;currencyId'));
```

& in html should be `&amp;`